# ASP.NET Binding integer to CheckBox's Checked field

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, listview, checkbox, bind

I have a following ListView item template, in which I am trying to bind integer value to `Checked` property of CheckBox.

`IsUploaded` value contains only 0 and 1...

```
<asp:ListView ID="trustListView" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="isUploadedCheckBox" runat="server"
            Checked='<%# Bind("IsUploaded") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

But ASP.NET complains that

> Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Sepcified cast is not valid

Even though following code using `DataBinder.Eval()` works,

I need to have a 2-way binding, thus need to use `Bind()`.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="isUploadedCheckBox2" runat="server"
    Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(
        DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IsUploaded"))) %>' />
```

**How can I convert 0's and 1's to boolean using `Bind()`**?

---

**[ANSWER]** 
I have extended auto-generated type through partial class by adding a new property mentioned in the [answer by Justin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561382/asp-net-binding-integer-to-checkboxs-checked-field/1561480#1561480)

Comment: Is making "IsUploaded" a bit or other boolean datatype instead of an int an option?

Comment: @kscott: "IsUploaded" is a bit.

Comment: What kind of datasource are you binding to? Binding a checkbox to a bit using an objectdatasource pointing to a table adapter works with no errors for me.

Comment: @kscott: It is an auto-generated type from Entity framework.

Comment: I don't know why I cannot Upvote.  Anyways, sorry about not being able to vote all great answers here.  It says that I cannot upvote unless the answers are *edited*??? ...

Comment: hmmmm, weird. that doesn't make much sense.  I'd be happy to edit my answer if that opens a torrent of votes. :-)

Comment: @Justin: Thanks for editting.  I was able to upvote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're willing to change the class, add a property on the class that's a boolean

```
public bool IsUploadedBoolean
{
   get { return IsUploaded != 0; }
   set { IsUploaded = value ? 1 : 0; }
}
```

If not, you may have success with a TypeConverter:

1. Create a custom [TypeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx) which will handle 0 and 1 to boolean conversions
2. Stick the [TypeConverterAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverterattribute.aspx) on the IsUploaded property to direct .NET to your custom typeconverter.

Answer (score 3):

How about adding a property to your class which does the conversion?

```
public bool IsUploadedBool
{
  get { return IsUploaded == 1; }
}
```

and then bind to this `IsUploadedBool` property instead of directly to the underlying INT.

Marc

Comment: @marc_s: You meant double "==" not "=" :)

Answer (score 2):

Kind of a cheesy work around would be to use a drop down list with list items to give the same effect:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBool" runat="server" SelectedValue= '<%# Bind("IsUploaded") %>'>
    <asp:ListItem Text="True" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="False" Value="0" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Sorry scott but I have to stick to "CheckBox" for my particular case.  But thank you for giving me an insight on this.

Comment: @kscott: Would you be able to make change to your answer? (add a dot or etc.) so that I can upvote your answer?  I consider your answer to be a valid option for my case as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For more information visit:
http://dhondiyals.wordpress.com/2010/05/03/binding-checkbox-with-integer-value-in-gridviewtrick/

Answer (score 1):

How about (btw i am using a stored procedure)

Aspx page

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="social_facebook" runat="server"  Checked='<%# Bind("True") %>' />Facebook
```

Code behind

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_facebook", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = social_facebook.Checked;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Hi, I'm also using Ajax rating inside a GridView and I ran into this problem. After looking through several forums, I tried this and it worked for me. I hope it helps you:

```
<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("EVALUATION")) %>
```

returns an integer, since you're using Checked which is an integer.