# checkbox updating features

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox

I have 20 checkboxes to deal with, but I don't want to write 20 IFs like

```
      If MGTReview.GetCPO = 1 Then
            Checkbox1.Checked = True
        Else : Checkbox1.Checked = False
        End If
```

in the data pulling, then write 20 IFs like

```
          Dim CPO as boolean
           If Checkbox1.Checked = True, CPO=1
          Else: CPO=0
          End If
```

So I have a registered user control, and the public property is below:

```
    Public Property checkResult() As Integer
    Get
        Return _checkResult
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _checkResult = value
        Select Case _checkResult
            Case 1
                CheckBoxA.Checked = True
            Case 0
                CheckBoxA.Checked = False
        End Select
    End Set
      End Property
```

and my vb code behind the page is

```
        Checkbox2.checkResult = MGTReview.GetCPOP
        Checkbox3.checkResult = MGTReview.GetCCA
        Checkbox4.checkResult = MGTReview.GetCCAP
        Checkbox5.checkResult = MGTReview.GetCR
        Checkbox6.checkResult = MGTReview.GetCP
```

...

Now the conversion from 1 to checked=true works well, and I can see them on the website. But if I unchecked a box and click "update", my value does not change from 1 to 0.

I wonder what class should I write? Should I write another public property (I'm actually new to public property)?

Thanks for advice!

Comment: How is your update codes?

Comment: You might want to consider more descriptive names for your checkbox controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is really how you want to do it, I think it would be easier to do something like:

```
chkCPOP.Checked = (MGTReview.GetCPOP = 1)
```

You might want to look at databinding the checkbox controls, have alook at this question:
[ASP.NET Binding integer to CheckBox's Checked field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561382/asp-net-binding-integer-to-checkboxs-checked-field)

Comment: That looks great! I will get a try and let you know the result! Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Thanks very much! It works pretty well! I can forget about the registered user control for now.